# Xamarin Object instantiation is null

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I've got a ContentPage which is always null when instantiated from Code.  The xaml itself is straightforward:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
>          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
>          xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
>          xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
>          mc:Ignorable="d"
>          x:Class="Galaxy.Views.DispatchFormViewer"
>          Visual="Material"
>          BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackground}"
>          xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
>          ios:Page.UseSafeArea="True">
> <ContentPage.Content>
>     <ScrollView>
>         <StackLayout x:Name="FormStackLayout" Padding="5"></StackLayout>
>     </ScrollView>
> </ContentPage.Content> </ContentPage>
> ```

and the code behind is (fields, properties and constructors only):

```
  [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class DispatchFormViewer : ContentPage
    {
        private int ExpandableCount;
        private DateTime CreationDate;
        private int FormID;
        private int DraftID;
        private int JobID;
        private int NewStatus;
        private bool IsCancellation { get; set; }
        public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
        public bool IsMediaTransition { get; set; }

        public DispatchFormViewer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public DispatchFormViewer(ContentView mainView, int formID, int draftID, int jobID, bool cancellation, int newStatus, DateTime startDate)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FormStackLayout.Children.Add(mainView);
            FormID = formID;
            DraftID = draftID;
            JobID = jobID;
            IsCancellation = cancellation;
            NewStatus = newStatus;
            CreationDate = startDate;
            ExpandableCount = 1;
        }
```

however even a simple:

```
var navPage = new DispatchFormViewer();
```

returns null in the navPage object.  There are no errors that I can see, and nothing in the output that would suggest anything wrong.  I have another control which is almost identical where this works.

I'm tearing my hair out as to how a constructor can return null!  I've inherited a xamarin project from another dev and I've never worked in it before so aren't really sure where to begin looking.

This is happening on the Android Simulator.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you getting a null ref exception at runtime?  Are you **positive** that it is the page itself that is null, and not some other object?  What does the stack trace show?

Comment: I'm not getting any null reference exceptions at all.  Code carries on, but leaves the navPage object as null (then meaning I can't access its properties later on).  Call stack doesnt show anything odd, just the reference for the code??  As for it being another object - I'm at a loss there, sorry

Comment: can you provide some more context about how you're creating and using navPage?  If it's null and you try to access a property it should throw an exception.

Comment: actually, I renamed the variable and that seems to have fixed it.   Must have been a leak or something somewhere.  thanks for the help in pointing me!

Comment: @user3502087 seems that you solved your problem, please share a solution as answer, it maybe help others.